# Maven - maven-war-plugin to generate jar and install it to maven local repository

Tags: java, jar, war, vs-web-application-project, maven-war-plugin

I am using maven-war-plugin in my `pom.xml` to generate a `jar` file in parallel with my `war` file in an `java web project` build. My `maven` build is creating `war` and `jar` files in the target directory. And only `war` file is installed to local repository. Is there a way to push the `jar` file created as well to local repository. Below is the snippet of my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>             
        <archive>
            <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
            </archive>
            <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/x*.jar</packagingExcludes>
        <webXml>${project.basedir}\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
         <webResources>
        <resource>
          <directory>${project.basedir}\src\main\webapp</directory>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*.*</include>
          </includes>
        </resource>
            </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Thanks in advance!

pom.xml content:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>x</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>x</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>             
                    <archive>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                        </archive>
                        <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/x*.jar</packagingExcludes>
                    <webXml>${project.basedir}\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                     <webResources>
                    <resource>
                      <directory>${project.basedir}\src\main\webapp</directory>
                      <includes>
                        <include>**/*.*</include>
                      </includes>
                    </resource>
                        </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
              <groupId>com.googlecode.addjars-maven-plugin</groupId>
              <artifactId>addjars-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>1.0.2</version>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-jars</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
              </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: What parts of your webapp are included in the jar file? What is the purpose of the jar file?

Comment: Only java compiled classes is part of my jar file. This jar file is used for other module build. In other module build i am just mentioning this jar in dependency. So, which will be looked for in maven local repository. So, i want my first module build to push its jar to local repository.

Comment: What goals do you start?

Comment: @wumpz i have added my pom.xml content in my question

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you can't move these classes into a regular jar project and then add it as a dependency to your webapp (as well as the other module)?

Comment: I want both war and jar files as the output of this build. War is for deployment and jar is for other modules build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the right way to use maven. Maven is all about modularity and as a consequence there is a "one project - one artifact" rule (or recommendation). See also this blog if I can't convince you : [How to Create Two JARs from One Project (…and why you shouldn't)](http://blog.sonatype.com/2010/01/how-to-create-two-jars-from-one-project-and-why-you-shouldnt/#.VFjH-BZaXGY) . It is about multiple jars but the concept is the same.

I think you should restructure your work into having one separate project for the jar, while the others use it as a dependency.

Comment: Ok sorry. As i am new to maven, i combined up my tasks in a single build. So then i will try to separate out tasks as two different builds. But, FYI when i tried to find out a way i found maven-war-plugin with archiveClasses tag set to true, did the task i wanted to.

Comment: archiveClasses only packages your classes into a jar and places it to the /lib of your target. It will not install it in your local repo however. According to the plugin documentation "you can deploy the classes and resources included in your webapp as an 'attached' artifact". You may try it by also using attach-classes in addition to archiveClasses

Comment: yes, <attach-classes> configuration is creating my output jar file with name <artifactId><version>-classes.jar in the target folder and installing the same to local repository as well. Thanks you. Its a good thing to know!

Comment: I added this change to my project pom.xml in Eclipse but the jar isn't also being generated for some reason, tried both 2.6 and 3.0.0. Are we suppose to point to a place to export it? Any idea why?